# Iterate over DOM & form a JSON object

Tags: json, dom, loops

I am iterating over DOM & trying to create a JSON object using javascript. Following is the code-

```
<div id="div1" class="clickDiv" style="position: absolute; left: 259px; top: 32px; border: 10px none;">
```

Save

The following function is executed when a button is clicked to save the DOM id & their respective styles in a JSON object.

```
 function savecomm(){
var values = [];
var html = [];

$(".clickDiv").each(function() {

        values.push($(this).attr("id"));
        var styleProps = $(this).css( ["position", "left", "top"] );
        $.each( styleProps, function( prop, value ) {
        html.push( prop + ": " + value );
        });

}); 
console.log(values);
console.log(html);

}
```

Am getting the following in the console:-

```
["div1", "div2", "div3"]
["position: absolute", "left: 712px", "top: 31px", "position: absolute", "left: 872px", "top: 25px", "position: absolute", "left: 587px", "top: 19px"]
```

I would like to relate the div1 to its respective styling & save it as an JSON object. For example:-

```
div1:[position: absolute", "left: 712px", "top: 31px",], div2:[position: absolute", "left: 602px", "top: 51px",]
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, `values` and `html` are simply arrays. And even the result you want is just a normal object. [There is no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, using the ID as a key:

```
function savecomm() {
    var values = {};

    $(".clickDiv").each(function () {
        var html = [];
        var styleProps = $(this).css(["position", "left", "top"]);
        $.each(styleProps, function (prop, value) {
            html.push(prop + ": " + value);
        });
        values[$(this).attr("id")] = html;
    });
    console.log(values);

}
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks for the solution Mike & a quick reply.